# Sqlite trigger to delete records takes too long

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I've like 50,000 records in my DB. I have maintained the trigger such that , when it crosses 50,000 records i.e 50,001 record, I'll delete the first 49000 records and keep only the last 1000.

The trigger is set by a python script and the insertion to the DB is also donee by the python script.

The problem here is that deleting the rows into DB through the trigger is taking too long...

I've heard doing in python is much slower than in the command line, when I do it through the command line, it took me like 10 to 15 seconds, and through python, when it inserts 50,001th record and tries to delete the previous 49,000 records, the program doesn't finish the task.

I waited about for half an hour, and it's still executing. What should I do?

PS : The trigger is perfectly fine.

```
    sql = '''CREATE TRIGGER autodelete AFTER INSERT ON syslog
           WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syslog) > '''+self.size_limit+'''
           BEGIN
           DELETE  from syslog where time < ( select time from syslog limit -1 offset '''+str(self.co)+''');
       INSERT INTO syslog (loglevel, logcode,logmessage) SELECT level loglevel, code  logcode,message logmessage FROM syslog_default_codes where ROWID=1;
           END'''
```

This is my trigger , and this is my insert

```
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO syslog (loglevel, logcode, logmessage) values (?, ?, ?)', (loglevel, logcode, logmessage))
        self.con.commit()
```